# Building CSS with Tailwindcss not working

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css

I am pretty new to Tailwind and CSS as a whole and am trying to build this CSS file:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

.btn{
    @apply rounded-full py-2 px-3 uppercase text-xs font-bold cursor-pointer tracking-wider
}
```

With this command

```
npm run build-css
```

But I get this response

```
> course@1.0.0 build-css C:\Users\user\Tailwind\project
> tailwindcss build src/styles.css -o public/styles.css

[deprecation] Running tailwindcss without -i, please provide an input file.

Done in 3220ms.
```

And nothing happens. How do I specify the input file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As error says, you need to provide input file with `-i` flag. Change your script inside `package.json` to this

```
tailwindcss -i src/styles.css -o public/styles.css
```

More information about Tailwind CLI is [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#using-tailwind-cli)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below command,

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/tailwind.css -o ./dist/tailwind.css
```

Where the file after `-i` is your source css file where you have extracted the custom css components and `-o` is where you want your final build file.

For more, have a look at the link in tailwindcss website - [Using Tailwind CLI](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#using-tailwind-cli)