# Build Tailwind Deprecation Error Shows Up When Building

Tags: tailwind-css

Inside my package.json file I have a command under scripts below:

```
 "scripts": {
    "build-css": "tailwindcss build src/styles.css -o public/styles.css"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.4"
  }
}
```

Here is my file structure

[image: file structure here]

When I try to use my build command and run `npm run build:css` I get this error

> [deprecation] Running tailwindcss without -i, please provide an input file.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong if I already specified the path under scripts doesn't that mean I already included the input file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Building CSS with Tailwindcss not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68054520/building-css-with-tailwindcss-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include the `-i` option and the path to that file when building your CSS [using a custom CSS file](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#using-a-custom-css-file). For example, change the `build-css` script in your package.json to be the following.

```
"scripts": {
    "build-css": "tailwindcss build -i src/styles.css -o public/styles.css"
},
```