# deprecation Running tailwindcss without -i, please provide an input file?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am trying to run css tailwind on my device and it works. But it shows me every time I create a tailwind CSS file.

```
[deprecation] Running tailwindcss without -i, please provide an input file.
```

I do not understand why?

Comment: you have not configured the local setup properly

Comment: You have to include the -i option and path to that file when building your CSS, Please check this doc https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#using-a-custom-css-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build Tailwind Deprecation Error Shows Up When Building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68331814/build-tailwind-deprecation-error-shows-up-when-building)

Comment: I used to run TailwindCss projects without adding -i

Answer (score 3):

With -cli@latest it should work just fine.

```
npx tailwindcss-cli@latest build css/tailwind.css -o build/main.css
```

Answer (score 0):

[Accoridng to the latest Tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)

The 'build' command has been replaced with '-i' as in this code.

`"build-css": "npx tailwindcss-cli -i src/style.css -o style.css"`

I tried it and it worked for me

Answer (score -1):

From tailwindcss docs https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#using-a-custom-css-file

/* ./src/tailwind.css */

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .btn {
    @apply px-4 py-2 bg-blue-600 text-white rounded;
  }
}
```

/* terminal */

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/tailwind.css -o ./dist/tailwind.css
```